# Crop image according to frame of any View

Tags: ios, image, crop

I have an image and I want to crop it according to frame of any view. For example;

I really can't find the solution. I have been searching it for 2 days.

[BEFORE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ1aG.jpg)

[AFTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FArxR.png)

**EDITTED**

Thanks to @Ajharul Islam and @Bence Pattogato. Both of answers work.

**Swift version of @Ajharul Islam 's solution.**

```
      func images(byCroppingImage image: UIImage?, to size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        // not equivalent to image.size (which depends on the imageOrientation)!
        let refWidth = (image?.cgImage?.width)!
        let refHeight = (image?.cgImage?.height)!


        let x = (Double(refWidth) - Double(size.width)) / 2
        let y = (Double(refHeight) - Double(size.height)) / 2



        let cropRect = CGRect(x: CGFloat(x), y: CGFloat(y), width: size.width, height: size.height)


        let imageRef = image?.cgImage!.cropping(to: cropRect) as! CGImage

        var cropped: UIImage? = nil
        if let imageRefs = image?.cgImage!.cropping(to: cropRect) {
            cropped = UIImage(cgImage: imageRefs, scale: 0.0, orientation: UIImage.Orientation.up)
        }


        return cropped
    }
```

**Let me tell my mistake and what was i trying for**

I was trying  take picture and crop it according to any view's frame. I was trying to crop the picture without resize it according to that main view. So it was cropping from wrong way every time.

I resized the picture and now I can successfully crop picture. But resizing  reduce picture's quality. So now I am tring to find the best method.

Thank you

Comment: Do you need to export image or just for viewing purpose  ??

Comment: I actually need to store cropped image, in variable. So I can reuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can crop image using this code :

```
   - (UIImage *)imageByCroppingImage:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)size
{
    // not equivalent to image.size (which depends on the imageOrientation)!
    double refWidth = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
    double refHeight = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);

    double x = (refWidth - size.width) / 2.0;
    double y = (refHeight - size.height) / 2.0;

    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(x, y, size.height, size.width);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], cropRect);

    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:0.0 orientation:self.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return cropped;
}
```

pass your image and rect of the view you will get a cropped image from center

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to achieve it is the following:

```
extension UIImage {
    func crop(to rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
        guard let imageRef = cgImage, let cropped = imageRef.cropping(to: rect) else {
            return nil
        }
        return UIImage(cgImage: cropped)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the 
[CIAffineTransform](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIAffineTransform) or the [CIPerspectiveCorrection](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPerspectiveCorrection). I am not sure which is better for your use case but they should work both. For example you can use the CIPerspectiveCorrection like that:

```
(CIImageToWorkWith).applyingFilter("CIPerspectiveCorrection", parameters: [
                            "inputTopLeft" : CIVector(cgPoint: topleft),
                            "inputTopRight" : CIVector(cgPoint: topright),
                            "inputBottomLeft" : CIVector(cgPoint: bottomleft),
                            "inputBottomRight" : CIVector(cgPoint: bottomright)
                            ])
```

edit: You don not want to crop the Image. Cropping is like cutting out something from an Image without scaling it.